# Flask -- instantiating an object from external doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: javascript

I'm just starting with Flask, so I may be overlooking something very obvious.  I have loaded my javscript file with this:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='Page.js') }}"></script>
```

then I try to instantiate an object from that js file:

```
<script>
    var page = new Page("index");
</script>
```

In Page.js, I have this:

```
var Page = function(page) {
    alert("init");
    <some other things>
    }
<and then some object methods Page.prototype.init_standard = function() {} etc>
```

The alert isn't alerting, though I am expecting it to.  Also, if I put an alert before the instantiation in the HTML page, I get the alert, if I put an alert on the line after the instantiation on the HTML page, I don't get the alert.  I'm not sure if this is a Flask issue or javascript -- I'm quite new at both.

EDIT: To nip this possibility in the bud, the javascript file is getting loaded according to the development server, status 304

Comment: Try debugging with the browser dev tools. 'ctrl+shit+i'. There is probably a javascript error. Check the error console. You can also set breakpoints and step through the code.

Comment: I just did that and it tells me Page is undefined.  I'm not sure why.  I've done it this way dozens of times and it works, just never with Flask.  Does Flask do something weird in loading statics?  Like they don't "run" them but just allow access?

Comment: If you open the debugger and you look at the `<script src=` line, where you're trying to load Page.js, do you see a well formed URL there? It sounds like the problem is that Page.js is not being loaded.

Comment: Another question, have you saved the file `Page.js` in the `static/` subdirectory of your project?

Comment: Yes, I said in the EDIT up there that the file is getting loaded, the server reports status 304.  It's in static.  I think I've figured out the problem.  I think there's a bug in the Page.js file preventing the variable Page from being set because when I remove everything except the class declaration, it works.  I'll try to find it.

Comment: I figured it out, it was because I was trying to do jinja parsing inside the javascript file and it didn't load properly as a result.  So I moved the parsing to the HTML and passed it in as an argument to the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after looking at the browser debugger.  It said Page was not defined.  After some trial and error, I realized I can't use {{ flask templating notation inside the javascript file, probably because it isn't loaded as a template so no parsing of it in that way occurs.  Anyway, I ended up just moving the {{ }} link to the html template and passing it in as an argument to the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Page.js needs to just define a function that creates the object you want. So Page() should just be a function that ends with 'return this;'. Correction returning this is not strictly required for object creation.

```
function Page(page) {
    alert("init");
    ... Your code and methods...
    // Example Method:
    this.foo = function(param) {
        ... function body ...
    };
    return this;
}
```

And then you can create an object with:

```
var page_object = new Page("index");
page_object.foo(some_data);
```

Comment: I've never seen a javascript object created that way.  Is there something about Flask that requires it to be done this way?  I've always done it the prototype route.

Comment: I'm in the habit of using Factory functions and yes explicitly returning this is not required in JavaScript. Nothing about Flask specifically effects how JavaScript runs in the browser.

Comment: What about this would fix the problem?  The debugger shows "Page" is undefined.  I would think it was undefined how I was doing it, it would be undefined this way, as well, no?